# Samsung Galaxy s2 not showing missed calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, call-history

My phone won't show any missed calls. I have a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S2. It was working earlier today. I called my phone 3 times because I was looking for it. But when I found it, it didn't show any missed calls. It won't even show up on the call log either.

How do I get it back to showing my missed calls?

Answer (score 1):

You could change the way the logs are "viewed by". Go to logs-->settings-->view by-->all logs.
If it is already on all logs, then quite possibly the logs are full, try deleting some or all of the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Logs, press `Menu`, select `View by`, then select `All logs`.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is an easy method.

Go to notification panel by swiping from top to bottom.

You can see all missed calls

Comment: If they were logged that is. As the OP describes, they were not – so it's unlikely they are found in the notification area if they are not even in the call log.